# Ruby variable assignment in a conditional "if" modifier

Tags: ruby, if-statement, variable-assignment, local-variables

I have a question about how the Ruby interpreter assigns variables:

I use this quite often:

```
return foo if (foo = bar.some_method)
```

where some_method returns an object or nil.

However, when I try this:

```
return foo if (true && (foo = bar.some_method))
```

I get: NameError: undefined local variable or method foo for main:Object.

What is the difference in evaluation between the first and second lines that causes the second line to error?

Comment: Because the assignment will be short-circuited in the second variation. But meh, I'm not sure this is a pattern that lends itself to readability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Read it carefully](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods) :

*Another commonly confusing case is when using a modifier if:*

```
p a if a = 0.zero?
```

Rather than printing `true` you receive a **NameError, “undefined local variable or method 'a'”**. Since **Ruby** parses the bare `a` left of the `if` first and has not yet seen an *assignment* to a it assumes you wish to call a method. Ruby then sees the *assignment* to `a` and will assume you are referencing a `local method`.

The confusion comes from the ***out-of-order execution of the expression***. **First the local variable is assigned-to then you attempt to call a nonexistent method.**

As you said - None `return foo if (foo = bar.some_method)` and `return foo if (true && (foo = bar.some_method))` will work, I bet you, it wouldn't work, if you didn't define `foo` before this line.

Comment: Damn I thought I deleted this question! I realized shortly after I posted that I had already defined foo in irb when I tested this out. I'll leave up this evidence of my noobness for others to learn from. Thanks for answering.