# ruby inline while vs while end

Tags: ruby, while-loop, inline

Why does this work:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
while n = a.shift
  puts n
end
```

while this doesn't:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
puts n while n = a.shift
```

It works only if I initialize `n` in advance:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
n = nil
puts n while n = a.shift
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21740291/

Comment: There are a number of parser issues related to LALR descent that affect Ruby post-conditions. They are bugs, but nobody ever opens bug reports about them. See [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25820190/1301972) for a similar problem with the :if_mod token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is, in general, an interpreter problem, that could not appear in languages with local [variable bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing), like javascript.

The interpreter (reading from left to right) meets right-hand-operand `n` before any mention of it.

The more I think about it, the more I am convinced it is a bug in ruby interpreter. As @Cary pointed out, the control flow is in fact the same:

```
a = [2, 3]
n = 1
puts n while n = a.shift
#⇒ 2
#⇒ 3
```

No trail of `1` in the output above.

Comment: Good explanation. You might want to add another case: the second example preceded by `n = 0`.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, the second example with `n = 0` preceeded, is written in the pseudocode _exactly_ as the first one, that is why I decided to omit it. *UPD*: Oh, wait. I will, thx.

Comment: I suggested that because I thought some readers might think `0` might be printed in that case.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks a lot, actually my previous answer was confusing, I have it completely re-written.

Comment: The control flow is irrelevant. The `n` in `puts n` is a method call since at that point a local variable called `n` isn't defined according to the from left to right reading parser. It's just a local variable quirk that would require special-casing.

Comment: It's not a bug in the interpreter. It's a misfeature of the LALR descent parser in the way it handles post-condition tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding: `puts n while n = a.shift`,

it will pares `puts n` first, but `n` is undefined at that point. Ruby is a dynamically typed language; you don't declare variable type explicitly, but you should assign a value to variables.

For example:

```
irb(main):027:0> xyz
NameError: undefined local variable or method `xyz' for main:Object
irb(main):028:0> xyz = 1
=> 1
```

Comment: It _tries to parse_ `puts n` first, not _executes_.

Answer (score 1):

`n` is undefined at the time you attempt the first `puts`.  The condition, and corresponding `shift`, is only checked after the `puts` has been evaluated.  An alternative which *will* work as you expected would be

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
puts a.shift while a.length > 0
```